# How do I control Hellmouth?

Tags: hellmouth

I just got [Hellmouth](http://www.hellmouth.website/) in a Humble Bundle, and while it seems interesting, I just can't figure out how to play it.

I assume I need to move ingredients to my plate, but aside from using the cursor keys to move, I can't perform any of the moves my AI opponent can.

Since there are no help files in or out of game, I'm really at a loss as to what to try next other then just mashing keys.

**How do I do anything in Hellmouth?**

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, the keys I've been able to find are:

## Player 1

- Movement: Cursor Keys
- Attack: <kbd>B</kbd>
- Jump: <kbd>N</kbd>
- Grab/Release: <kbd>M</kbd>

## Player 2

- Movement: WASD
- Attack: <kbd>R</kbd>
- Jump: <kbd>T</kbd>
- Grab/Release: <kbd>Y</kbd>

I'm not sure if there are more that I'm just missing.